# SQL Query multiple databases

Tags: sql-server

I need to run a `SELECT` query on a SQL Server and return info pulled from multiple databases on the same server. I have the following, which could work:

```
SELECT [Name], [Nationality]
FROM [dbtest].[dbo].[Staff]
WHERE Nationality = 'Canadian'

Union all

SELECT [Name], [Nationality]
FROM [dbtest2].[dbo].[Staff]
WHERE Nationality = 'Canadian'

etc..
```

The problem is I have 2000 databases to query and it will almost certainly be added to in future, meaning the query will need editing.

What I really need is a wildcard for the database name.

ie:

```
*.[dbo].[Staff]
```

but this gives me an error. Even if it worked, not all databases have the same tables, so is likely to error anyway.

Any way I can do this without typing out the above example 2000 times ?

Comment: Good point, Yes they are. Sorry, forgot to mention that. have added that in now

Comment: What about differences between tables i those databases ? Can you specify kind of differences you are expecting ?

Comment: To clarify that a little, the databases that contain the required info will have all the same tables/structure, but other databases may exists that don't contain the query specified tables. ie: sys databases and any miscellaneous

Comment: It might be better idea to collect the results for example to a temp table one by one rather than creating a huge union all statement with all the databases at once -- and then you can just execute the same statement in each of the databases.

Answer (score 3):

You can build the statement dynamically

```
DECLARE @Query varchar(max) = ''

SELECT @Query = COALESCE(@Query + ' UNION ALL ', '') + 'SELECT [Name], [Nationality] FROM [' + TABLE_CATALOG+'].dbo.[Staff] WHERE Nationality = ''Canadian'''
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name = 'Staff'

SET @Query = STUFF(@Query, CHARINDEX('UNION ALL', @Query), 10, '')

PRINT @Query

EXEC(@Query)
```

Comment: Thx for your reply Yosi. This executes successfully but returns 0 rows. Am I supposed to be adding to this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting the same. It executes successfully but returns 0 rows.

Comment: I've printed the query. You should expect it to be the same as what you wrote in the question. Good luck debugging :)

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing that is to generate query on the fly.
Either by querying `information_schema` DMV as in @Yosi answer or by using your own *metadata table* (in case tables can have different names in different databases or there are any other significant differences in table's schema) :

1. Create some *master* database and create table here which will contain list of all other databases - mainly DB name but you can include any other information describing differences (and use this data during query generation). You can add more (or delete) database "definitions" here.
2. Create stored procedure which will iterate *master table* and generate query on the fly
3. Execute query using `sp_exec`