# SQL Query against multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to run a query against multiple databases on the same server.

I need to pull all the values from 2 tables in a database based on a criteria from a 3rd table in the database, if the database was created after a certain date.

I have a query to find when the database was created:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.databases
WHERE STATE = 0 --ignores offline databases
AND database_id > 4 --does not include master, model, msdb, tempdb
AND create_date > CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-01')
```

And the query that I need run on each database is generally as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.Column6=Table1.Column2
AND Table3.Column3='Value1'
AND Table3.Column4='Value2'
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table3.Column6=Table2.Column2
```

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547177/sql-query-multiple-databases), which is essentially would I would like to do, but when I look at the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES the TABLE_CATALOG column does not have the table names I would like to query against. I thought I could try pulling the names from the sys.databases table like above, so I tried modifying it to:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(max) = N''

SELECT @cmd += COALESCE(@cmd + ' UNION ALL ', '') + 'SELECT *
    FROM [' + name + '].dbo.Table1
    INNER JOIN [' + name + '].dbo.Table3 on Table3.Column6=Table1.Column2
    AND Table3.Column3= ''Value1''
    AND Table3.Column4=''Value2''
    INNER JOIN [' + name + '].dbo.Table2 on Table3.Column6=Table2.Column2'
FROM sys.databases
WHERE STATE = 0
AND database_id>4
AND create_date>CONVERT(datetime,'2021-08-26')

SET @cmd = STUFF(@cmd, CHARINDEX('UNION ALL', @cmd), 10, '')

PRINT @cmd

EXEC(@cmd)
```

But when I run it with a date earlier than 2021-08-26 (which grabs more than 5 tables), I get a memory error. I need to run this at least to the beginning of April (preferably up to the beginning of the year) which will grab around 500 tables.

What is the recommended way to run a query against multiple databases in SQL?

Comment: `I get a memory error.` -> there are a _lot_ of possibilities here. Could you be more specific? Also why are you looking in `sys.databases` for table names? It contains database names, not table names. Are you trying to get data from Table1, Table2, etc. that exist in multiple databases, or are you trying to get data from multiple different tables in a single database? Please be more specific about your requirements (the date, or that there are 500 tables, etc. are largely irrelevant details). And what version of SQL Server?

Comment: This sounds like an issue from design rather than a query. Are you creating multiple copies of the same database over time?

Comment: The memory error was " Msg 701, Level 17, State 123, Line 1
There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query."
Yes, that was a typo. Looking for database names in sys.databases. The 3 tables each with the same name in different databases.
SQL Server version 2018

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server 2017? 2018 sounds like the client tool, Management Studio, not the server version (`SELECT @@VERSION;`).

Comment: Yeah sorry, It's Server version 2016 and Management Studio version 2018.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be instead of trying to build one massive `UNION ALL` dynamic SQL statement, that you build a #temp table to hold the results of each output, and then it's much easier to send *the same string* to each database:

```
CREATE TABLE #hold(dbname sysname, Column1 {data type}, ...);

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @exec nvarchar(1024);

SET @sql = N'SELECT DB_NAME(), *
  FROM dbo.Table1
  INNER JOIN dbo.Table3 
   ON Table3.Column6 = Table1.Column2
  AND Table3.Column3 = ''Value1''
  AND Table3.Column4 = ''Value2''
  INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 
   ON Table3.Column6 = Table2.Column2;';

DECLARE @dbname sysname, @c cursor;

SET @c = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY FOR
  SELECT name FROM sys.databases
  WHERE state = 0 -- ignores offline databases
    AND database_id > 4 -- does not include master, model, msdb, tempdb
    AND create_date > CONVERT(datetime, '20210101');

OPEN @c;

FETCH NEXT FROM @c INTO @dbname;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SET @exec = QUOTENAME(@dbname) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';
  INSERT #hold EXEC @exec @sql;
  FETCH NEXT FROM @c INTO @dbname;
END;

SELECT * FROM #hold;
```

You might also consider investing in `sp_ineachdb`, a procedure I wrote to help simplify running the same command in the context of each database.

- [Execute a Command in the Context of Each Database in SQL Server using sp_ineachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5686/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-using-spineachdb/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Execute a Command in the Context of Each Database in SQL Server - Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Comment: I am wondering if you have any resources to read into how the cursor works. I will definitely check out the sp_ineachdb procedure you wrote up.
Quick addendum. Is it possible to add the dbname to the insert statement? I'm not sure I entirely understand how it works to modify it

Comment: @kennyh I added db name to the #temp table and the SQL output. The cursor just loops through each database name that matches the criteria, then executes `EXEC dbname.sys.sp_executesql @sql;` - this way you are running the SQL in the context of that database, so you don't need to mess around with using square brackets and manually prefixing every table with a potentially unsafe name.

Comment: Great. Thanks, Aaron!